# Is there any possibility to send post with body using OAuth 1.0?

Tags: c#, .net, wordpress, post, oauth

i am trying to send a POST request with body to WordPress API. I am still getting 401 error.

I decided to use: https://gist.github.com/DeskSupport/2951522 to authorize via OAuth 1.0 and it works perfectly with GET method. Then i wanted to implement another method which sends simple body.

That's my code:

```
            var oauth = new OAuth.Manager();
            oauth["consumer_key"] = _consumerKey;
            oauth["consumer_secret"] = _consumerSecret;
            oauth["token"] = _accessToken;
            oauth["token_secret"] = _tokenSecret;


            var appUrl = _baseUrl + url;
            var authzHeader = oauth.GenerateAuthzHeader(appUrl, "POST");

            string body = GenerateBody(parameters);
            byte[] encodedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(appUrl);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authzHeader);
            request.ContentLength = encodedData.Length;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            newStream.Write(encodedData, 0, encodedData.Length);

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {

                }
            }
```

The result of method GenerateBody is `user_login=login&user_pass=BXE&04K44DoR1*a`

I also tried to change the '&' character to '%26' but it didn't work.

This request works via Postman and i don;t know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found a solution.

https://blog.dantup.com/2016/07/simplest-csharp-code-to-post-a-tweet-using-oauth/

This guy wrote the way to make this request. What is also important you have to change a oauth_nonce for unique token.